# Click Event Hash # URL

Tags: jquery, url, hash

Hello I have this URL `example.com` which has a div called
`<div class="terminosycondiciones"</div>`

This div invokes a popup of terms and conditions.

I need to call this popup only with url when user put it in browser
`example.com#termsandconditions`

As I would do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(
    window.location.hash &&
    window.location.hash.substring(1) === 'termsandconditions'
) {
    // Do your stuff
}
```